# Add a key value pair in config file at runtime in Azure Webrole

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, azure-web-roles

I want to add a key value pair to Azure web role `web.config` file at run time using `c#`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we ended up doing.

We added a Key with blank value in web.config and then added a value to it at run time. I think the same code can modified to add both Key and value pair at run time.

```
            using (var server = new ServerManager())
            {
                    var siteNameFromServiceModel = "Web";
                    var siteName =
                        string.Format("{0}_{1}", RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id, siteNameFromServiceModel);

                    string configFilePath = server.Sites[siteName].Applications[0].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath + "\\Web.config";
                    XElement element = XElement.Load(configFilePath);

                    element.Element("appSettings").Elements("add").Where(X => X.Attribute("key").Value == "YourKeyName").Single().Attribute("value").Value = "YourValue";
                    element.Save(configFilePath);
             }
```